# Setting Correct Boolean Conditions

Tags: javascript

I am working on practicing booleans (where in the code below, I'm representing the number of times a fruit is counted, essentially that number will be what they can afford to the price, if that makes sense) and the code I am working on seems to be working, but the conditionals I have set are only returning as false and not as true and vice versa when they are swapped.

I'm just wondering if there is an issue with the logic that I currently have.

Here is the data that I have:

```
items = {
    count: 100,
    fruits: [
      { id: 'apple', price: 50 },
      { id: 'orange', price: 200 },
      { id: 'banana', price: 500 }
    ]
  };
});

    ('returns true if the person can afford the item', function() {
      const result = code.affordItem(items, 'apple');
      expect(result).to.be.equal(true);
    });
    ('returns false if person cannot afford the item', function() {
      const result = code.affordItem(items, 'orange');
      expect(result).to.be.equal(false);
```

Here is the code that I have:

```
  function affordItem(items, itemId) {
  if (items.count >= items.fruits.quantity && items.fruits.id === itemId) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Comment: Your code is looking for `items.fruits.quantity`, but that doesn't appear in your `items` object.

Comment: `items.fruits` is an array, you have to index it. `items.fruits[0].quantity` will be the quantity of `apple`.

Comment: But there are no `quantity` properties in any of the elements, just `id` and `price`. So it's really unclear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
function affordItem(items, itemId) {
  if (items.count >= items.fruits.length && items.fruits.id === itemId) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Try this, i assumed you want to get the quantity of fruits so use array.length instead.